# BigQueryIO - only first day table can be created, despite having CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a dataflow job processing data from pub/sub defined like this:

**read from pub/sub -> process (my function) -> group into day windows -> write to BQ**

I'm using **Write.Method.FILE_LOADS** because of bounded input.

My job works fine, processing lots of GBs of data but it fails and tries to retry forever when it gets to create another table. The job is meant to run continuously and create day tables on its own, it does fine on the first few ones but then gives me indefinitely:

`Processing stuck in step write-bq/BatchLoads/SinglePartitionWriteTables/ParMultiDo(WriteTables) for at least 05h30m00s without outputting or completing in state finish`

Before this happens it also throws:

`Load job <job_id> failed, will retry: {"errorResult":{"message":"Not found: Table <name_of_table> was not found in location US","reason":"notFound"}`

It is indeed a right error because this table doesn't exists. Problem is that the job should create it on its own because of defined option **CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED**.

The number of day tables that it creates correctly without a problem depens on number of workers. It seems that when some worker creates one table its **CreateDisposition** changes to **CREATE_NEVER** causing the problem, but it's only my guess.

The similar problem was reported here but without any definite answer:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3772?focusedCommentId=16387609&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16387609

ProcessElement definition here seems to give some clues but I cannot really say how it works with multiple workers: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/WriteTables.java#L138

I use 2.15.0 Apache SDK.

Comment: There is currently an ongoing discussion on this PR https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/9556 and the BEAM-3772 JIRA.

Comment: Hi, I face the exact same issue for the same use case, on the latest Beam release (2.27.0), did you find a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue, which is still not fixed in BEAM 2.27.0 of january 2021. Therefore I had to develop a workaround: a custom PTransform which checks if the target table exist before the the BigQueryIO stage. It uses the bigquery java client for this and a Guava cache, as well as a windowing strategy (fixed, check every 15s) to sustain a heavy traffic of about 5000 elements per second. Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/matthieucham/85459eff5fdea8d115be520e2dd5ccc1

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in the past that caused this error, but that particular one was fixed in commit https://github.com/apache/beam/commit/d6b4dcec5f297f5c1bd08f345f0e1e5c756775c2#diff-3f40fd931c8b8b972772724369cea310 Can you check to see if the version of Beam you are running includes this commit?

Comment: In addition, if you are using DynamicDestinations, make sure that your destination function is deterministic. The code assumes that a single DestinationT deterministically maps to a single BigQuery table.